# iOS add constraint for bottom of view to container center

Tags: ios, xcode, view, constraints

I am trying to add a constraint for a UIView in iOS7 for aligning the bottom or top of a view to the center of its containing view.

Example: 
LabelViewContainer contains 2 labels: label1, and label2. 
The 2 labels should be aligned to the LabelViewContainer's center: label1's bottom should be 3 pixels above the center, and label2's top should be 5 pixels below the center.
The constraints I see in xcode allow me only to align the center of the labels to the center of the container whereas I would actually want the bottom or top of the labels to be above or below the container's center.

The only solution i've found so far was to add another hidden view which is centered with the container, and has a size of 0. Then have constraints for the labels with leading/trailing spaces to the new view.
I was hoping there was another solution that doesn't require inflation of a dummy view.

EDIT:
the size of the label views is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions:

- Two `UILabel`s with height of 30 and width of 280 starting a x = 20

Now... Lets see how to tackle your case.

### Step 1:

Place the `UILabel` anywhere you want

---

### Step 2:

Select both `UILabel`s and set these common constraints
[image: Common Constraints]

---

### Step 3:

Select Top most `UILabel`

Since you want it 3px above the center, note that it's height is 30.
If it were at the center, the `UILabel`'s center would be at the `view`'s center and so... if you took it up by half it's height (*of 15px*) then it's bottom edge would be touching the center line.
Now, take it 3px higher and you have it 3px above the center line.

Hence you need it `18px` higher than the center line.
Which means you need to specify a constant of `18` when aligning it to the center of the view.
You can do it so:

[image: Label1 Constraint]

---

### Step 4

Select Top most `UILabel`
Update the frame to conform to this constraint.

[image: Label1 Update frames]

---

### Step 5

Select the other `UILabel`

Since you want it 5px below the center, note that it's height is 30.
If it were at the center, the `UILabel`'s center would be at the `view`'s center and so... if you took it lower by half it's height (*of 15px*) then it's top edge would be touching the center line.
Now, take it 5px lower and you have it 5px below the center line.

Hence you need it `20px` lower than the center line.
Which means you need to specify a constant of `-20` when aligning it to the center of the view.
You can do it so:

[image: Label2 Constraint]

---

### Step 6

Select other `UILabel`

Update the frame to conform to this constraint.

[image: Label2 Update frame]

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. i did learn a few new things here.
nevertheless in my problem, the height of the label view is not known (or might change in run-time). i will update my question accordingly.
can you think of a way around this?

Comment: @ItayBianco : hmm... so how have you been doing it all this while? i.e. show how you were programmatically setting the constraints and lets see what we can do

Comment: first off, i was thinking it would be best not to rely on sizes as the design might change to a new font thus changing the size of the label view. i would rather not depend upon the label size. although it is possible.

in any case, the current solution i made was as i mentioned in the question, which was to add a view that is centered in the parent, and add a constraint between the bottom of the upper label and the bottom of the new view. since the new view has a size of 0, it in effect creates a constraint between the parent's center and the upper label's bottom.

Comment: @ItayBianco : well... at some point, you **will** have to set the height in which case, you just pick up the height (after it's determined) and modify your constraints accordingly.

Comment: so would you suggest overriding the constraints in run-time according to the size of the label view? that would be a solution. although i was hoping there was a way to make a constraint between bottom of one view and center of another without playing around with the sizes (instead of constraints only between the same locations in both views).

Comment: @ItayBianco : hm... there may be but none that I am aware of (_right now_)